# ERROR trying to load Data to Google Collab from disk

Tags: google-colaboratory

i am trying to open and load some data from disk in Google Collab but i get the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-cc9c795dc8d8> in <module>()
----> 1 test=open(r"C:\Users\Stefanos\Desktop\ΑΕΡΟΜΑΓΝΗΤΙΚΑ PUBLICATION\data\test.txt",mode="r")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Stefanos\\Desktop\\ΑΕΡΟΜΑΓΝΗΤΙΚΑ PUBLICATION\\data\\test.txt'
```

the error occurs by this code:

```
test=open(r"C:\Users\Stefanos\Desktop\ΑΕΡΟΜΑΓΝΗΤΙΚΑ PUBLICATION\data\test.txt",mode="r")
```

Comment: Does the following work? `test = open(r"C:\Users\Stefanos\Desktop\test-PUBLICATION\data\test.txt", mode="r")` (without `ΑΕΡΟΜΑΓΝΗΤΙΚΑ`)

Comment: @ack the answer below is the solution. i just needed to upload the file and then to load them to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to load from disk with path of your computer!

Collab gives you a completely different computer in the cloud to work with so it wont be able to open the files in your computer:

You have to upload files to collab:

Use this function to upload files. It will SAVE them as well.

```
def upload_files():
  from google.colab import files
  uploaded = files.upload()
  for k, v in uploaded.items():
    open(k, 'wb').write(v)
  return list(uploaded.keys())
```